# Adding a file to a specific folder of zip archive

Tags: php, zip

I've got a zip archive (Open Document Spread Sheet - ods) containing this structure:

```
Configurations2   | File Folder
META-INF          | File Folder
Pictures          | File Folder
Thumbnails        | File Folder
meta.xml          | XML Document
mimetype          | File
settings.xml      | XML Document
styles.xml        | XML Document
```

What I want to do now is adding two files to the zip archive

1. one file named `content.xml` to the **root** of the .ods structure
2. another file named `image.png` to the **./Puctures** Folder

Adding a file to the root of a zip archive is not a problem

```
// `$zipfile` contains the sructure as desribed above
// `$content_xml` contains a xml string
// `$image` contains the `image.png`
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipfile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$zip->addFromString('content.xml',$content_xml);
$zip->close();
```

How can I add `$image` to `./Pictures`?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use PHP but can't you simply add files with the full path like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.ziparchive.php#109618):

```
$zipFile->addFile($folder . $f, $subfolder . $f);
```

**edit:**

Just checked it ... works just fine. Assuming ZIP contains an `icons` folder following code works (if not, add one with `addEmtpyDir('icons')`):

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('./test.odt', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$zip->addFile('./favicon.ico', 'icons/fav.ico');
$zip->close();

?>
```